# Problems in create function

Tags: python, python-3.x

That's my first question, I'm new at programming, sorry about any inconvinience !

I need to finish an exercise that consists in create a fuction to find the higher number and another function to find the lower number on a List, but when I print the results, it keeps giving me a wrong answer.

Here is my code:

```
lista_numeros = [1593, 200, 72, 8, 423, 2, 39, 293, 20120]

def menor_numero(arg1):

    colector1 = arg1[0]

    print(coletor1) # - Checking value added to COLECTOR1

    for a in range(len(arg1)):

           print(arg1[a]) # - Checking if the A argument is running through the list.

           if colector1 < arg1[a]:

                     colector1 = arg1[a]

    return colector1


resultado2 = menor_numero(lista_numeros)

print("menor ", str(resultado2)) # Result is the last position of the list, must be the 6th position.
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Seems like your indentation is a little off, the pasted code is equal the one that you are running? And could you add your output?

Comment: are you sure your `arg` holds numbers, not text?  we cant see from the code you posted. Please make your code a real [mcve] including your data, your expected output and any error message you get. thanks

Comment: Oh, I've edited guys! Sorry about that! 

Thank you for the atention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist of all indentation is very important in python to tell it the order to execute your code and also to define where code sits within a loop etc.

Now you say you want to make a function that finds the smallest and largest number from the output of another function, for this I will assume this output is a list.

Please see code below with comments.

```
Mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] #assume this is output from other funtion

def func(alist): #define function
    collector1 = 100 #keeping your collector idea
    for i in alist: #iterate through input
        if i < collector1: #check if the item you are currently looking at is smaller than the item currently stored in collector
            collector1 = i #if is smaller overwitre colletor with new item
    print(collector1) #after iterating through all items in input print final value of colletor

func(Mylist) #call function with input
```

This outputs,

```
1
```

Simply change this,

```
    if i > collector1:
```

And it will now find the largest in input, so output is now.

```
9
```

Edit: if you are looking for the smallest number start collector1 at a large number, if you are looking for the largest start collector1 at = 1.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your input is a list and not a string or some sort you can just use the min()/max() methods:

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5]

print(max(myList)) >> 5

print(min(myList)) >> 1
```

you can find more info here : 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/list_max.htm
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/list_min.htm

Comment: Hi Brandon!

Didn't know about that methods!

Thank you very much for share this, really appreciate!

Comment: no worries! feel free to set this answer to "answered" and vote it up!. it helps me out a lot ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your function is finding the maximum instead of the minimum value. Changing the `<` to `>` should do what you want.

Python also has builtin methods `min()` and `max()` which should do what you want.

Comment: Oh, I see! Got it!

Thank you very much Ryan!

Answer (score 0):

```
#! python3

import random

numbers = []
max = 1000
min = 0

for i in range(40):
    numbers.append(random.randint(min,max))

maxNum = min
minNum = max

for num in numbers:
    if num > maxNum:
        maxNum = num
    elif num < minNum:
        minNum = num

print(maxNum, minNum)
```

This is my code, I use the random library in python to generate a random list of numbers, then I set max to equal the maximum number in that list.

The following for loop generates 40 random numbers and appends them to my list.

I then set maxNum to equal zero, so everything will be greater than it, thereby the initial value will not influence the outcome, and then I set minNum to equal max, so every number will be less than it.

The last block of code loops through the numbers list, and compares every number with the current maxNum and minNum variables to see whether that number is greater than the max or less than the min. If it is, the maxNum (or minNum) number will be updated and the code will move on to the next number.

The last statement prints or minimum and maximum values.

I don't know what course you are taking, but I would advise you to familiarize yourself with this code and understand what it is doing, as it's pretty basic and the stuff you encounter in the future will be much harder.